# Is "mispuncture" an actual word?

Tags: word-usage

How can I express the action of incorrectly puncturing a vein or missing it?

Can I just say "mispuncture"?

Comment: "mis-" is a legitimate prefix for active verbs.

Comment: If you missed the vein completely you failed to puncture it- you didn’t mispuncture it.  In the same easy that mistyping implies you typed something but it was incorrect or misnaming implies it was named, but incorrectly.

Comment: @Jim but you did puncture something (presumably skin) just not the vein as intended. Similarly (mistype), you typed something, just not the word you intended. That said, I can’t find any easy official references or ngrams, so it would be difficult to look it up if you could identify the prefix.

Comment: @Pam, yes you’ve clearly mispunctured, but you haven’t mispunctured ***the vein***.

Comment: I think that the word 'mispuncture' would always require some added context since it is not clear exactly what the result would be, whether leaving an intact vein or leaving a damaged vein.

Comment: So vein mispuncture means puncturing the vein in an incorrect way like damaged it

Comment: I found a phrase "misplaced puncturing" to express the act of puncturing the skin and missing the vein completely

Comment: I actually wonder what *puncturing a vein* means in the first place. I mean, in practical terms where *mispuncturing* could take place. Inserting a needle or IV? We would just say that. (Although, in this case, it would be *incorrectly inserting a needle or IV*.) I'm not really coming up with a scenario where *mispuncturing a vein* would *ever* be used. "Oh, my God! I punctured his vein by accident!" Sure. But not, "Oh, my God! I *mispunctured* his vein by accident!" Is there any medical procedure (or otherwise) where you would be instructed to *puncture a vein* (and be able to get it wrong)?

Comment: The common expression when failing to draw blood is *I couldn't find a vein.*

Comment: @Jason straight through and out the other side? In a ham-fisted way leading to a lot of bruising? It still seems unlikely

Comment: @ChrisH Hmm. Yes, I can see how that might apply. Although I think other descriptions might be more likely . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"incorrectly puncturing a vein or missing it"

Firstly, *mispuncture* is an established "word" in the context of surgical practice.

Secondly, it signifies an action of puncturing, so "incorrect puncturing" would qualify as a *mispuncture,* but missing a right vein would not.

Btw, missing the vein alone cannot be a cause for anxiety, but puncturing the wrong vein very often is.